# Cant receive Udp in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was trying to send udp packet from wp7 emulator to my server (java server on same pc -) and get some response. I've used the code of SocketClient class from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202864(v=vs.105).aspx .

It works totally fine when:

1. Every time I create the instance of Socketclient class and call send() and receive() method.
2. after sending a packet using send() I can receive several packet calling receive() several.

But the problem is-

1. I create the instance of Socketclient class and call send() and receive() method then again call send() and receive() (from same object of Socketclient class).In this situation It can send the packet second time bt cant receive (gives response "operation timeout").

If I create a new object of Socketclient class for sending and receiving again it works but I have to use a single socket all time in my project.How can I solve this?
Here is the code-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
namespace UdpClient
{
    class SocketClient
    {
        // Cached Socket object that will be used by each call for the lifetime of this class
        Socket _socket = null;
        // Signaling object used to notify when an asynchronous operation is completed
        static ManualResetEvent _clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        // Define a timeout in milliseconds for each asynchronous call. If a response is not received within this
        // timeout period, the call is aborted.
        const int TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 5000;
        // The maximum size of the data buffer to use with the asynchronous socket methods
        const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        /// <summary>
        /// SocketClient Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public SocketClient()
        {
            // The following creates a socket with the following properties:
            // AddressFamily.InterNetwork - the socket will use the IP version 4 addressing scheme to resolve an address
            // SocketType.Dgram - a socket that supports datagram (message) packets
            // PrototcolType.Udp - the User Datagram Protocol (UDP)
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Send the given data to the server using the established connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serverName">The name of the server</param>
        /// <param name="portNumber">The number of the port over which to send the data</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data to send to the server</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the Send request</returns>
        public string Send(string serverName, int portNumber, string data)
        {
            string response = "Operation Timeout";
            // We are re-using the _socket object that was initialized in the Connect method
            if (_socket != null)
            {
                // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                // Set properties on context object
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(serverName, portNumber);
                // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
                // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
                socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                    // Unblock the UI thread
                    _clientDone.Set();
                });
                // Add the data to be sent into the buffer
                byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);
                // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
                _clientDone.Reset();
                // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
                _socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);
                // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
                // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
                _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
            }
            else
            {
                response = "Socket is not initialized";
            }
            return response;
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Receive data from the server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="portNumber">The port on which to receive data</param>
        /// <returns>The data received from the server</returns>
        public string Receive(int portNumber)
        {
            string response = "Operation Timeout";
            // We are receiving over an established socket connection
            if (_socket != null)
            {
                // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
                // Setup the buffer to receive the data
                socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
                // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
                // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
                socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                        response = response.Trim('\0');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                    }
                    _clientDone.Set();
                });
                // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
                _clientDone.Reset();
                // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
                _socket.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);
                // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
                // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
                _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
            }
            else
            {
                response = "Socket is not initialized";
            }
            return response;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes the Socket connection and releases all associated resources
        /// </summary>
        public void Close()
        {
            if (_socket != null)
            {
                _socket.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the receive function. The packet data was assigned to the string response asynchronously but it was returning the variable response from the current thread before completing the receiveAsync operation.